# Mini-game with Python 3.2 does not work

Tags: python, python-3.2

```
from random import randrange
def init_config(m, n):
    print("""CrÃƒÂ©e une configuration pour la configuration initiale""")
    config = [[0 for a in range(n)] for b in range(m)]
    for k in range(m*n): a, b = k//n, k%n
    config[a][b]=k+1
    return config
def disp(config, m, n):
    print("""Affiche un damier d'une configuration existante avec le format voulu""")
    s=t=" +%s\n" % ("---+"*n)
    for k in range(n):"%s %s" % (" "if k==0 else "",chr(65+k if k<26 else 71+k)),
    for k in range(m*n): i, j=k/n, k%n
    s +="%s%s|%03d%s"%(k/n+1 if k%n==0 else ""," "if k%n==0 and k/n<9 else "",config[a][b],"|\n" + t if b == n-1 else "")
    return s
def set_treasure (config):
    import random
    a=random.randrange(0,lin)
    b=random.randrange(0,col)
    treasure=config[a][b]=0
def main():
    print("Entrer les dimensions du damier")
lin=int(input('nombre de lignes : '))
if type (lin)!=int :
    print(""" ***ERREUR !***\n le nombre de lignes doit etre un nombre entier""")
    lin=int(input('number of lines : '))
elif lin>26:
    print(""" ***ERREUR !***\n le nombre de lignes ne doit pas excÃƒÂ©der 26 !""")
    lin=int(input('nombre de ligne : '))
col=int(input('nombre de colonne: '))
if type (col)!=int :
    print(""" ***ERREUR !***\n le nombre de colonnes doit etre un nombre entier""")
    col=int(input('nombre de colonne: '))
elif col>38:
    print(""" ***ERREUR !***\n le nombre de colonnes ne doit pas excÃƒÂ©der 38 !""")
    col=int(input('nombre de colonne: '))
n_treasure=int(input('Combien de trÃƒÂ©sor voulez vous mettre dans le jeux: '))
if type (n_treasure)!=int :
    print(""" ***ERREUR !***\n le nombre de trÃƒÂ©sor doit etre un nombre entier""")
    n_treasure=int(input('nombre de trÃƒÂ©sor que vous avez demander dans le jeux: '))
config=init_config(lin,col)
for k in range (n_treasure):
    if set_treasure (config):
        board=disp(config, lin, col)
        print(board)
for a in range (lin):
        for b in range (col):
            if config[a][b]==0:
                print("Il y a un trÃƒÂ©sor dans", chr(65+b),a+1)
```

hello all , I just finished this mini game with python 3.2 but the problem is that the program does not work I do not find the problem, i have `TypeError: Win32RawInput() takes at most 2 positional arguments (4 given)`

Comment: `input("Il y a un trÃƒÂ©sor dans", chr(65+b),a+1) ` you are accept input from user in this statement?

Comment: i made mistake, i haven't to use input but print

Comment: Now i have another problem NameError: name 'n_treasure' is not defined , I think it's a spacing problem , what do u think ? Vivek Sable

Comment: @AbdéNour can you include the traceback of your error regarding `n_treasure`.

Comment: @Tanveer Alam Message File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> C:\Users\ABD\programme cherche trésor.py 48  
NameError: name 'n_treasure' is not defined

Comment: `nombre de lignes : 10
nombre de colonne: 20
Combien de tr├â╞Æ├é┬⌐sor voulez vous mettre dans le jeux: 30
Cr├â╞Æ├é┬⌐e une configuration pour la configuration initiale
('Il y a un tr\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa9sor dans', 'A', 1)
('Il y a un tr\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa9sor dans', 'B', 1)
('Il y a un tr\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa9sor dans', 'C', 1)
...........`
I ran your script and it did worked. I didnt got any exception.

Comment: yes it works , thank u , it was a problem of spacement for me, thank u much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if config[a][b]==0:
   input("Il y a un trÃƒÂ©sor dans", chr(65+b),a+1)
```

So here you are passing four arguments to the built-in function [**`input`**](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) which takes at most one argument.

```
input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> string

    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
    If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
    On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
    is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

Comment: thank u, i made a stupid mistake,i had to put "print" instead of "input" input take at most one argument u are right ! merci :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided any explanation of what the program should actually do and I don't speak French, here's what I think is the problem: In the last line

```
input("Il y a un trÃƒÂ©sor dans", chr(65+b),a+1)
```

you try to display several different types as the input question. But from the context, I think what you really want to do is print these types. Do this by simply typing:

```
print("Il y a un trÃƒÂ©sor dans", chr(65+b),a+1)
```

Perhaps the same goes for fifth-to-last line. It should be

```
print(board)
```